# Generating function of linear recurrence relation, initial value problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I tried to solve the following problem:

> What is the generating function of the following recurrence relation?
> $$a_{n} = 3a_{n-1} + 1, 1\leqslant n, a_0= 2$$

First, I multiplied by $x^n$:

$$a_n x^n = 3a_{n-1} x^n + x^n$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n x^n= 3x \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} x^n$$

$$F(x) - a_0 = 3x F(x) + x \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$F(x) - 2 = 3x F(x) + x \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$F(x) -2 = \frac{3x}{1-x} + x \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$F(x) = \frac{3x}{1-x} + x \frac{1}{1-x} + 2$$

I got stuck in here. I know how to solve a problem like this, when there isn't a plus constant number, so I tried to solve using that method:

$$a_n - 3 a_{n-1} = 1$$

$$a_1 = 3a_0 +1 = 7$$

$$a_2 = 3a_1 + 1 = 22$$

$A = 2 + 7x + 22x^2 + ...$

$3xA = 6x + 21x^2 + ...$

$(1-3x)A = 2 + x + x^2 + ... $

$A = 2 + \frac{x}{(1-3x)(1-x)}$

What should I do differently? And what is the correct solution of this problem?
I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: The recurrence is valid only for $n \ge 1$, but you have summed over $n \ge 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claude Leibovici's method is good, but if you want the generating function, you basically found it already. Just solve the equation,
$$
F(x) - 2 = 3x F(x) + \frac{x}{1-x}
\implies F(x) =  \frac{2-x}{(1-x)(1-3x)}
.
$$
(At this point you instead seem to have substituted $F(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ in your working, which was wrong). Now, if we want to extract coefficients from this, I'd do partial fractions,
$$
F(x) = \frac{5}{2(1-3x)} - \frac{1}{2(1-x)} .
$$
From this, you should easily be able to find an expression for $a_n=[x^n]F(x)$ yourself.

EDIT: In your last equations, you also get the right answer except for an arithmetic error:
$$
A = \frac{2}{1-3x} + \frac{x}{(1-3x)(1-x)},
$$
which is equal to $F(x)$ above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

To solve $$a_{n} = 3a_{n-1} + 1$$ since the problem is the constant, let $a_n=b_n+k$ and replace
$$b_n+k=3b_{n-1}+3k+1$$ So, make
$$k=3k+1\implies k=-\frac 12\implies b_n= 3b_{n-1} $$ which is simple